# is the summary() adequate to visualize the intractions among variables in GLMs?

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, ancova

Good afternoon,
I'm fitting a GLM with Poisson distribution. Based on the information collected from Zuur et al. (2009) entitled "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R" I noticed that the summary() function is used to visualize the effect of the independent variables over a dependent one. However, during the frontal lessons of biostatistics performed at the University, my professor told me that it is not the best way as the summary function best suits with linear regression models. He affirmed that for non-linear models it's better to use the ANOVA function (in this case called ANCOVA) combined with the chi-squared test (i.e. ANOVA(GLM, test="Chisq") when the residuals' distribution is known (i.e. binomial, Poisson, negative binomial) or combined with the Fisher's test when the residuals' distribution has to be determined (i.e. gaussian, lognorm, gamma, exponential). Unfortunately, I do not have bibliographic references and I do not have very clear ideas about that. Please, is there anyone who can help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in the effects size (that only the `summary` output can give you) or the significance of the interaction? Note that a GLM is a linear regression model, hence, it's called a *Generalized **Linear Model***.

Comment: Dear Dr. Roland, thanks for your reply. I'm interested in the significance of the interaction. What is the best method? Furthermore, based on what you said, hence, even the GLMMs are linear models as are called Generalized Linear Mixed Models. Is this correct? Many thanks.